# Images appear to not scale up with the size of the screen

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I have created a centered layout. But it does not scale images up to device's dpi. How to make them bigger as device screen? Also how to scale them even in editor? Cause I can't. They are always this size.

Here is an example of ImageButton code:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/broadcasts"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:onClick="onWipButton_Click"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView5" />
```

Folder structure with all dpi.

[image: Folder structure with all dpi.]

On device with high dpi.

[image: On device with high dpi.]

Design mode in studio.

[image: Design mode in studio.]

Comment: use fixed widths and heights instead of wrap content

Comment: @MohammedAtif scaling the images will make them blurry.

Comment: @weston yes i know that, scaling the images **might** make them blurry. it depends on the image too. gor example if u want your image to be 150dp on xxhdpi device and what you have is 400px image, scaling it up to 450px will not cause much blur. yes, ideally image should match the size of placeholder, but little scaling is acceptable

Comment: @MohammedAtif In this case, to match the design time look shown, we're talking about roughly doubling the size of the images, not +12%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have actually do have assets of different sizes in those resource folders at zoom levels of 1x, 1.5x, 2x, 3x, 4x for m, h, xh, xxh, xxxh.

Then understand that devices are not fixed width either physically or in terms of `dp`s. So while it may be correctly picking the correct resource for the resolution of the screen, that does not mean it will take up the same % of available width on every device. It should just be roughly the same physical size if measure with a ruler (roughly the same mind you).

In the designer, pick a screen with the same width and DPI. You should see the issue at design time.

If you want larger images, providing larger assets would be the simplest solution, and won't make blurry scaled images.

Then if you want the larger images only for larger screens, you could provide the larger assets in a drawable folder for large screens:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/
res/drawable-sw600dp-mdpi/
res/drawable-hdpi/
res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/
etc.
```

`sw600dp` is a "smallest width" qualifier, meaning it applies when the device has at least 600dp width available to it. This is a commonly used number to distinguish devices, it's what used to be known as a `large` screen. If you want to support different assets for 10" tablets, you might also use `sw720`.

Please see here for more info on the screen size resource folder qualifiers: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: does that mean I have to create new layout for each display size?

Comment: Na, I've just added more detail. You can do all with different resource folders.

Comment: Hey @NapoleonTheCake if this sorted your issue, please upvote and accept.

Comment: I also had to create layouts for every dp like 320dp, 480dp etc.